# iframe width attribute is being ignored

Tags: css, iframe, width

I would like to embed an slideshare presentation within a tooltip.
generally I want my tips to change their height/width dynamically based on their content hence I set (in my CSS)

```
width:auto;
height:auto;
```

I would like to have the width of the tooltip dictated by the inline width attribute of the iframe.

see here http://jsfiddle.net/elewinso/eNfHZ/

Comment: Don't use an iframe, they are not responsive and won't adapt to your content. The best you can do is a kind of ratio responsive hack but don't bother

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of `width: auto` depends on the properties of the element, and in this case, it means `300px`, as per clause [10.3.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-replaced-width) of the CSS 2.1 spec. The `iframe` element has no intrinsic width, and you cannot (in CSS) make its width depend on the content of the iframed document. It is part of the very idea of `iframe` that the iframed document is rendered autonomously, independently of the settings of the framing document, except that the latter sets dimensions on the inline frame, but it needs to set them in its own context (which does not include the content of the iframed document).

So if you want to have your tooltip rendered smoothly, just don’t use `iframe`. Instead, use content (static or script-generated) in the main document.

If you just want to have the HTML `width` attribute on the `iframe` element take effect, just don’t override it in CSS. *Any* setting of the `width` property of an element will make the `width` attribute on it null and void.

Answer (score 0):

100% width works:

```
div.sttip iframe{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/eNfHZ/1/

You won't be able to maintain aspect ratio though, you'll have to use Javascript to calculate the height using a onResize event handler.